# How to manage the number of loops in while loop Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm a beginner and wanna ask about While Loop Pseudocode for the number of loops if i want it to be entered by user and not specifying how many, should i write it like this? or i have to declare the SM first?

Thank you

```
   BEGIN
          Student = 0
          WHILE Student < SM
                      Get Work Efficiency, Task Completion Effectiveness, Team Work, SM # SM is 
                      the number of students’ marks to be entered
                      Sum = Work Efficiency + Task Completion Effectiveness + Team Work
                      Competency = (Sum / 50) * 100
                      If Competency >= 70%
                                       grade = ‘A’
                                       display = “Exceed Expectation!”
                      else if Competency >= 40%  AND  Competency < 70%  
                                       grade = ‘B’
                                       display = “Meet Expectation”
                      else if Competency >= 0%  AND  Competency < 40%  
                                       grade = ‘C’
                                       display = “Below Expectation”
                      else 
                                       display = “Invalid input”
                      End if
                      Student = Student + 1
          END WHILE
   END
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. "Pseudo-code" is a way to describe algorithms in a way that is understood by humans. As long as what you write is intelligible and unambiguous, you don't "have to" follow any specific conventions.

Comment: Research papers about computing often include pseudo-code of algorithms. Although those pseudo-codes follow no particular convention, they very often include two or three lines before the algorithm, to explicitly describe the input and output. For instance "**INPUT:** Number SM of students and list L of the students' grades; **OUTPUT:** Average grade; **ALGORITHM:** avg = 0; for g in L: { avg = avg + g; }; avg = avg / SM; RETURN avg; "

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, `SM` is provided by user's input, thus you should mention it somewhere. There is a lot of various ways of writing pseudocode and they mostly depend from your needs, so you could e.g. write:

```
SM <- integer user input
[rest of your code]
```

or wrap it in a function (that way you show that returned value is dependent from `SM`'s value:

```
function foo(SM):
    [rest of your code]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur answer, so if i want to make the number of loops as an input should i mention it before the while or it's ok to mention it with the other inputs just like what i did?

Comment: It usually depends on the loop you work with. In your case, you need to get some input in every iteration, thus your approach seems to be the best - you collect data only when you need it. When you work with pseudocode, you should think about which form fits your algorithm the most and which form is the easiest to read (in sense that people know what's going on in the algorithm).